# How to check for single regex in all form input values on change?

Tags: jquery, regex

My goal is to have a form that displays custom info for anyone who types in an email ending in ".ca". It's legal stuff, so I want this to trigger if they have a word/phrase anywhere in the form's input ending in ".ca" as soon as its typed, even if it isn't the dedicated email input.

```
$( 'input[type="email"],input[type="text"]' ).bind('input propertychange', function(){
  if ( /.ca$/i.test(jQuery( 'input[type="email"]' ).val() ) {
    // do stuff
  }
});
```

The problem with the above is that it works, but only on the first input if there is more than one input that matches what the regexp test is finding.

I realize I need to loop through all elements using .each, am not sure how the propertychange-on-bind is best utilized with .each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to loop.

Since you test on change of the value, you only need to check the current element

```
$( 'input[type="email"],input[type="text"]' ).bind('input propertychange', function(){
  if ( /\.ca$/i.test( this.value ) {
    // do stuff
  }
});
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you! I had also tried using "this", but did not think to use this.value.